# JasperServer: Schedule report at last day of month?

Tags: jasperserver

How to schedule report in JasperServer every last day of the month ?

I am trying to schedule a report, but I didn't find any option to get last day of the month like it would be variable eg in Feb it would be 29 or 28 and other may be 30 or 31. But How to specify this at the time of scheduling the report ?

Help me out..
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You can use *Scheduling Web Service* for it. You can find more info in [**JasperReport Server Web Services Guide**](http://jasperforge.org/espdocs/download.php?filename=/opt/jasper/www/espdocs/Documents/112/v4.2.1%20Documentation%20/JasperReports-Server-Web-Services-Guide.pdf&ctype=application/pdf)

Comment: I am using JasperServer UI only for Scheduling the reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible in the JasperReports Server UI today. The Quartz scheduler supports this, so it's certainly possible to get it working via customization (or possible to run the report via web services as Alex K suggests).

Often the reason for running a report on the last day of the month is to include the results from the past month. So it makes sense to schedule the report to run at a minute past midnight on the first of the month. Maybe you can get what you need like that.

Comment: yes for the time being I have done this only.. I have on every 1st date of month report will get generate for previous month.. Thanks for confirmation this approach